# Create a Ranking Distribution based on conditional ranting

Tags: r

I wanna ask your help with something, I need to calculate the movies better rated by people who liked the movie "Babe" (rating 4 or 5 stars), then provide the top 5 movies they liked most.

My fail attempt looks like this

This if for finding our the user that like Babe in the first time, so its only part of the question, but its not working

```
for(i in 1:length(datababe)){
  if(datababe[i] >= 4){
    print(datababe$User[i])
  }
}
```

Please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAR0w.jpg)

Comment: could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: the data is structure in the way that it has users are in the first column and in the other ones the name of the movies and the ranking from 1-5 giving by each user to each movie

Comment: It's hard to help if you do not provide an example

Comment: example of what?

Comment: Conditional ranting? Is that supposed to be "ranking"? I wasn't sure hence didn't edit the question myself.

Comment: Its conditional because it is based on whether the user give 4 or 5 as the rank, the idea is to have the total number of ranks above or equal to 4, divided by the total number of rankings per movie

Comment: provide a subset of your data frame

Comment: I post a link to an image on how the data is compose

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function is being applied to one rating at a time, so the sum of ratings >= 4 is always 1 or 0. The result will be either 0.25 or 0.20. Not what you want.

I created some fake data as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(users=sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=T),
               movie=sample(letters, 50, replace=T),
               rating=sample(1:5, 50, replace=T),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Use the `dplyr` package to filter out what you want as follows:

```
x<-data %>% 
    filter(rating>=4) %>%  # ratings you want
    group_by(rating) %>%   # grouped by the rating
    summarize(pct.4_5=n()/sum(data$rating)*100) # calculation; n() does counting
```

The resulting `tibble` will look like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  rating pct.4_5
   <int>   <dbl>
1      4    5.19
2      5    8.44
```

Comment: Thanks Edward the problem is that this only gives you the result for one movie = Rating, I needed it for all the movies [columns]

Comment: Now that you've added a look at your data structure, this works: `apply(data,2,function(x) {sum(x>=4, na.rm=T)/sum(x>0, na.rm=T)*100})`.